# Memory Usage of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, memory, sql

SQL Server instance on my server is using almost full memory available in my Physical Server.
Say if i am having 8GB of RAM than SQL Server is using 7.8 GB of RAM from system.
I also have read articles and also read many similar questions regarding same on this forum and i understand that memory is reserved and it is using memory.

But i have 2 same servers and 2 SQL Servers, why this is happening on a single SQL Instance not on other. Also when i run DBCC MemoryStatus than it is showing up...

```
VM Reserved 8282008
VM Committed 537936
```

so from this we know that SQL reserved whole 8GB memory, but why this VM Committed keeps increasing. What i understand is VM Committed is:

> *VM Committed: This value shows the overall amount of VAS that SQL Server has committed. VAS that is committed has been associated with physical memory.*

So this is the memory SQL Server has committed (from this i understand that physical memory actually SQL Server is using at instance).

So like to know the reason behind this ever increasing VM Committed memory on my server and not on another.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: not entirely sure what you are asking here....Are the servers set up identically? Do the sql server instnaces have the same config values?

Comment: Is there actually a problem here? does the amount of RAM used on one server being different to another really matter? Run sql profiler on both servers and compare the differences in commands being executed.

Comment: Actually different behavior is not an issue the only issue is to i like to know why exactly VM Committed is keep increasing, when i see process/queries running on SQL Server so i havn't found anything super heavy running on my instance so it is keep increasing. Any Help..??

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server is probably caching data in memory to speed queries in the future.

[SQL Server and RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450736/sql-server-and-ram)

I would guess that your two servers *are* under different loads.

Comment: @Tim... Right i have different loads on both of the servers.

Answer (score 0):

`VM Reserved 8282008` = The larger of your physical memory footprint and the configured memory settings, or:

```
SELECT CAST(value_in_use AS INT) * 1024 FROM sys.configurations WHERE name = 'max server memory (MB)' 
SELECT physical_memory_in_bytes / 1024 FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

`VM Committed 537936` = The actual memory used by SQL Server at this moment.